# Print a certain value from a list inside a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list which contains list of a song and its information.

```
table=[['lazy song','Bruno Mars','Pop','9']['Song name','Bandname','type','likes'].....]
```

How do i create a user input which print the list where a word of the user input is mentioned.

```
What you want it to be?= lazy
lazy song Bruno Mars Pop 9
```

Comment: If you work through tutorials on basic list access and string handling, you'll learn what you need for this code, and much more useful knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
for song in table:
    if user_input in song[0]:
        print (song[0], song[1], song[2], song[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to search on all fields and not just the song name then something like this should work:

```
table=[['lazy song','Bruno Mars','Pop','9'],['Song name','Bandname','type','likes']]

user_input = input("What you want it to be? ")

for song in table:
    for item in song:
        if user_input in item:
            print(song)
```

All songs that have a match in any of the fields will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` to check your sublists

list comphrension:

```
key = input()
lst = [i for i in table if any(j for j in i if key in j)]
```

Expanded with print:

```
for i in table:
    if any(j for j in i if key in j):
        print(i)
```